# Order of GARCH model

Tags: time-series, garch

I would like to ask, Is it possible to know the maximum order of GARCH(p, q); value of p and q (For example, using R software)automatically? 
         Example: In ArchTest, I got some where the result like the following

```
                   Chi-squared = 4.3044, df = 1, p-value = 0.0380

                   Chi-squared = 4.3892, df = 2, p-value = 0.1114

                   Chi-squared = 4.3927, df = 3, p-value = 0.2221

                   Chi-squared = 4.4637, df = 12, p-value = 0.9735
```

Therefore, Is it possible to know the value of p and q?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum order? p and q can be any integer numbers...

Comment: Yes Sashkello! I know that they can be any integer numbers, but for example in case of AR(p): One can know the value of p by plotting pacf() and in case of MA(q): One can know the value of q by plotting acf(). Then, my question here is:Is there any similar situation to know the value of p and q in GARCH (p, q) models?

Comment: Ah, from looking at the results of a model to find out which p and q produced it, right? Sorry, I'm not aware of any techniques to do this. You can try asking at http://quant.stackexchange.com

Comment: ya, sashkello! looking at the results of a model to find out which p and q produced!